# How to verify a std::array size during compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation, c++20

I defined a static constexpr std::array with string views like:

```
 constexpr int array_size = 6;
 static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, array_size> texts = {{"one", "two", "three"}};
```

During compilation, I want to check whether the size of the array (`array_size`) corresponds with the number of items in the array (which can be checked if the `string_view` is "" or filled). How to do this during compile time and show an error to the user if strings are missing in the `texts` array? Is this possible with a `static_assert` or are there other ways to achieve this in C++20?

Comment: Do you want to forbid explicit `""` usage, i.e `{{"a", "", "b"}}`?

Comment: If you can allow `""` in the middle, `static_assert(texts.back() != "")` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::to_array()` to specify only the element type, and have the size deduced. Then you can verify the size with a `static_assert`:

```
constexpr auto texts = std::to_array<std::string_view>({
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
});

static_assert(texts.size() == 3);
```

Also, if you don't need to override the element type, you can do this instead:

```
constexpr std::array texts = {"one", "two", "three"};
static_assert(texts.size() == 3);
```

In this case it will result in `const char *` being used as the element type.

Comment: Fine. But `using std::literals;` and `"one"sv` gets it done. I am allergic to  unsufixed string literals.

Comment: @Red.Wave And I'm still unable to get used to the suffixed ones.

Comment: Why not? I have seen you define complex ones.

Comment: @Red.Wave I don't mind UDLs in general, but I just can't make myself use `sv` by default for all strings, it somehow feels ugly. In the same vein, I prefer plain arrays over `std::array` by default, unless I have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Decaying is enough reason to avoid C arrays of any kind. Don't mind 10 more characters to type, when it avoids a potential safety risk. Pointers belong to data members; the only exception is extern interface to OS or other languge with ABI demands.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the size in your case as described in the body of the function, you can do the following,

```
template <std::size_t N>
consteval bool check_array_size(const std::array<std::string_view, N>& arr){
    return std::ranges::all_of(arr, [](auto sv){return !sv.empty();});
}

static_assert(check_array_size(texts));
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Y9Eezobj9

However, you should really consider whether you can eliminate the need to do so in the first place. For example by using

```
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;
static constexpr std::array texts = {{"one"_sv, "two"_sv, "three"_sv}};
```